# Installed PHP with brew but it is still not working

Tags: php, macos, apache2

I am trying to run a php webapp on eclipse, the mac already comes with PHP but I could not figure out how to get it to work so I decided to install it again using brew. I followed the steps in this tutorial https://aregsar.com/blog/2019/installing-php-on-macos/ and this one as well https://gist.github.com/karlhillx/791babda83495eab6fbf64f8a3270f86. I edited the httpd.conf file countless times and terminal shows the correct PHP version (8.0.2). I also added the java-bridge to the tomcat. When running a simple "Hello World" php file all I get is the code printed in the browser instead of the actual output. I can't figure out what I am missing.

This link contains the .conf files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lq8hk120vdqc2f2/AAB88VbjF3Eqr55d55cCsnE2a?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the PHP code you use, please. Sounds like the app is not being run via the web-server correctly.

Comment: @Mr.J I am running the following:
'<?php 
echo "Hello World"
?>'
I tried running this code using eclipse and I also tried to add it in the index file in a welcome folder under webapps. When I type http://localhost:8080/welcome/ in the browser, I get the following 404 error "The requested resource [/welcome/] is not available".

Comment: Can you run any of your other apps on localhost ok?

Comment: Yes I can run my jsp and html files just fine, my only problem is with php files

Comment: Tomcat is (almost) **never** used to run PHP scripts, the links you provide advise to use **PHP-FPM**. If you find references to `*.php` files in Tomcat's access log (not Apache's), there is something wrong with your config. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66233114/edit) you question and add the important parts of your `httpd.conf`. Look for the blocks containing `SetHandler`, `ProxyPass`, `FilesMatch`, etc.

Comment: I did just now, I do not know if there is anything else I should provide.

Comment: My guess is: you have a `ProxyPass` directive which sends everything to Tomcat indiscriminately. This directive should be restricted to the Tomcat application application prefix only.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that? I tried searching the httpd.conf file for ProxyPass but I couldn't find anything

Comment: The `httpd.conf` file can include other files (`Include` directive). E.g. the virtual host configuration is usually split into separate files.

Comment: There is an include statement at the end of the file:
`Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf`
Should I add another one or should I modify this one?

Comment: Please, include the content of all `other/*.conf` files in your questions.

Comment: I added a dropbox link above that contains these files

Comment: Your config files seem file, but you said you installed PHP 8, while in your config you load the `libphp7` module.

Comment: Any idea on how to load the PHP 8?